# Existing but unused API in SAP Commerce for Store Finder

Tags: spartacus-storefront

There are two API’s for SAP Commerce Store which are present in the Swagger API description but are not currently being used by the store finder page in Spartacus:
•   “/{baseSiteId}/stores/country/{countryIso}/region/{regionIso}”.
•   “/{baseSiteId}/stores/country/{countryIso}”

What is the best approach in Spartacus to add a new call for the following API: “/{baseSiteId}/stores/country/{countryIso}/region/{regionIso}”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OCC API has many endpoints that aren't necessarily used in Spartacus. There are either multiple endpoints to achieve the same thing, or a feature hasn't been build /finalised in Spartacus.

There are various ways to invoke a new API. One approach that is both clean and following the Spartacus architecture, is to customise the `StoreFinderService`. The `StoreFinderService` is a facade that acts in between the (more complex) state management layer, see diagram below.

[image: Spartacus data binding architecture]

If you'd add a method in a custom version of this facade, you could use the `httpClient` directly in the service. That is often enough, however if you like/need to store the response in the store, you could introduce custom state, or even extend the connector and adapters. Generally speaking, this complexity is not needed in a project implementation.